# Bash builtin (not SED!) search and replace using octal values

Tags: arrays, bash, replace, built-in

I'm having problems getting my code to work:

```
for (( c=1; c<=$DirsArrCnt; c=c+$OneDirArrCnt )); do 
    # Replace every occurence of "/" (ASCII d47 o057) in path with "^A" (ASCII 1)
    Hold="${DirsArr[$c]}"
    DirsArr[c]="${Hold//\057/\001}"
done
```

Originally I skipped the Hold variable and used the array element directly but took that out thinking it was the problem.

Am I specifying the octal value correctly? I believe 57 is the octal value for "/" right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you want :

```
DirsArr[c]="${Hold//$'\057'/$'\001'}"
```

The syntax you use interprets `\0` as a literal `0` (i.e. does nothing different compared to not using the backslash).  You need the C-style string to have your numeric code interpreted by the shell.

Comment: Wonderful. My echo of directory name (array key) shows up as funny characters instead of `/` that must be it. Thanks for the quick answer :)